# How does removeSpan() work?

Tags: android, spannable

Pardon me if I'm asking a dumb question but I would like to know how removeSpan() work without parameters start and end? How does it know the range of the text???
setSpan() has parameters start and end but removeSpan() does not.

Comment: when you call `setSpan` `start` and `end` is kept inside `Spannable` so it knows the range associated with your `span` when you call `removeSpan`

Comment: `removeSpan(Object what)` takes an object as parameter

Comment: You mean the parameter "what" contains the range?

Comment: no, `what` is a "span", a "span" you already added to your `Spannable` with `setSpan` method

Comment: ok,I understand.But there comes a new question:I use removeSpan() to remove the span from getSpans(start, end, StyleSpan.class) ,but it remove the style of the hold line ,not the start-end range.Could you tell me why it happens?

Comment: so you mean that `getSpans` doesn't work as expected? did you try to dump your spans with `TextUtils#dumpSpans` ?

Comment: I used getSpanStart(span) and getSpanEnd(span) to get the start and end of the span,but the results are different from the start and end i use in getSpans(start, end, StyleSpan.class)...